# how to scroll in a datatable in FLET.dev?

Tags: python, datatable, scroll, flet

I have a tab with some controls on the top and a table under the controls, i would like to keep the controls in place and only scroll the table.

Anyone can point me in the right direction please?

```
self.tab1_controls = ft.Column(
    controls=[
        self.tab1_status,
        self.tab1_button_row,
    ],
    scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO,
)

self.tab1_table = ft.Column(
    controls=[
        self.datatable_altered_alarmtexts,
    ],
    scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO,
)

self.tab1_content = ft.Container(
    content=ft.Column(
        controls=[
            self.tab1_controls,
            self.tab1_table,
        ],
        scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO
    ),
)
```

I've tried every possible combination i think with the ft.ScrollMode but no luck...